# Comparing elements of array with each other

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = ['This is text',
        'This is also text',
        'This is texts',
        'These are texts' ];

similar_text($arr[0], $arr[2], $percent);
echo $percent; // 96
```

I have an array with similar elements and I need to run the `similar_text` function on and remove elements with 90%+ matches.

How can I compare each element with every other to remove similar elements. Nested `foreach` loops or is there an elegant way with `array_filter`?

Comment: So you compare 0 and 2 and which one do you remove?  But neither is similar to 4...

Comment: You can get a situation where each element is 90%+ similar to the next, but where the first and the last are only 10% similar, yet all will be removed despite that. This is very fuzzy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested loops.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $i => $text1) {
    $keep = true;
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($arr); $j++) {
        $text2 = $arr[$j];
        similar_text($text1, $text2, $percent);
        if ($percent > 90) {
            $keep = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($keep) {
        $result[] = $text1;
    }
}
```

The inner loop starts after the current element of the outer loop, because previous iterations have already compared the earlier elements with everything.

Comment: Nice and simple, thats what I intended to do but since I'll be doing this over 100k times, I thought if there was a more efficient way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've changed the inner loop to use an index variable instead of `array_slice()`, which should be more efficient.

Comment: The bottleneck is all the comparing, and that's hard to avoid.